# Azure SDK + Java Libraries + Eclipse Plugin = One confused soul

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage-emulator

I followed these steps in the hopes of getting storage emulator on localhost working.

I am using Windows 8 RTM.

1. Downloaded [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/junor) and copied it to Program Files.
2. Installed Java [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7u7-downloads-1836413.html) 7.
3. Installed Azure [SDK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=252838&clcid=0x409).
4. Installed Azure [plugin](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/java-home/download-for-windows/) for Eclipse.
5. Launched storage emulator from the "Start" screen.
6. Created a Java project.
7. Added External [jars](http://dl.msopentech.com/lib/PackageForWindowsAzureLibrariesForJava.html) in the build path for Azure to this project.
8. Wrote this simple sample code:

   ```
   import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.blob.client.CloudBlobClient;
   import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.blob.client.CloudBlobContainer;
   import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.CloudStorageAccount;

   public class AzureStore {
       public static final String storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;"
               + "UseDevelopmentStorage=true;"
               + "AccountName=devstoreaccount1;"
               + "BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000;"
               + "AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==";

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           // Retrieve storage account from connection-string
           CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount
                   .parse(storageConnectionString);

           // Create the blob client
           CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
           // Get a reference to a container
           // The container name must be lower case
           CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient
                   .getContainerReference("tweet");

           try {
               // Create the container if it does not exist
               System.out.println(container.createIfNotExist());
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

It gives the following exception:

```
com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.StorageException: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:104)
at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.blob.client.CloudBlobContainer$2.execute(CloudBlobContainer.java:334)
at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.blob.client.CloudBlobContainer$2.execute(CloudBlobContainer.java:291)
at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.utils.implementation.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:110)
at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.blob.client.CloudBlobContainer.createIfNotExist(CloudBlobContainer.java:339)
at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.blob.client.CloudBlobContainer.createIfNotExist(CloudBlobContainer.java:257)
at AzureStore.main(AzureStore.java:26)
```

I am confused at this point, as what might be wrong. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is happening because of incorrect storage service version in the API. In your code you're trying to create a blob container in development storage. The "x-ms-version" request header value is sent as "2012-02-12" which though is the latest one but still not supported by the development storage. Development storage still supports "2011-08-18".

If you try your code against cloud storage, you should be able to create that blob container.

If you're only doing your development against development storage, one thing you could do is download the source code from GitHub (https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java/downloads) and modify the following line of code in Constants.java

```
public static final String TARGET_STORAGE_VERSION = "2012-02-12";
```

to

```
public static final String TARGET_STORAGE_VERSION = "2011-08-18";
```

and compile the source code again. This may break some new functionality introduced in the latest service release (like asynchronous copy blobs etc.)

Other alternative is to wait out for the new SDK to come out and hope that the emulator in that version support the latest storage service version.

Comment: Are the previous versions of the JAR release archived some place? Would you know?

Comment: I made the change, it did not work. Same error. I guess there are other places too probably.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't worked in Java for ages so I would not know how to compile the modified code. If you can share some instructions as to how to load the source code in eclipse and compile this (either using Eclipse or javac), I would love to give it a try.

Comment: JAR file can be opened by 7-Zip. I did this as a first try:

1. Open Jar file by right clicking and opening in 7-zip.

2. Dragged out the class file, tried a decompiler, modified the string, compiled to Java class file and dragged and dropped inside the JAR in 7-zip. Gave the same error.

Then I tried the proper way:
1. Downloaded from [github](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java) and used the README.md
2. Downloaded Maven and Installed following these [instructions](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/)
3. Did an mvn compile as per the README.md

Comment: 4. Now this dumps all the class files inside:
WindowsAzure-azure-sdk-for-java-da5d538\microsoft-azure-api\target\classes
5. At this point, open a new Java project in eclipse, In Package Explorer, right click project, properties, Java Build Path, Add External Class Path, Browse to WindowsAzure-azure-sdk-for-java-da5d538\microsoft-azure-api\target
6. Write a small piece of Azure code and run. While debugging if you get an exception and it opens the byte code in human readable format, you can Add Source and browse to the source directory to add file.

Comment: Constants$HeaderConstants.class is the right file to drag out, decompile, edit and drop back.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions. Man, it's tough :) So I changed the code to use older service version (2011-08-18) but I got the same result as you are getting. x-ms-version request header is still passed as 2012-02-12. I then hard coded this value in BaseRequest.java (createURLConnection function - retConnection.setRequestProperty(Constants.HeaderConstants.STORAGE_VERSION_HEADER,
                "2011-08-18");) and then I was able to create a blob container in dev storage. Not sure why it's not picking up this modified value. You may want to try that.

Comment: And I will be damned :) I reverted back those changes i.e. put back the version number in Constants.java and recompiled the source code and retried and it worked.

Comment: What did you do finally? i.e., just modifying Constants.HeaderConstants field worked? Why did it not work before? Did Microsoft release an automatic update while you weren't noticing :P

Comment: mvn clean. mvn compile. And voila! ...the compiler probably hard coded it. Thanks very much man!

Answer (score 0):

More about [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class

See if below works for you.

```
URI BlobEndPoint = new URI("http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1");

CloudBlobClient bClient = new CloudBlobClient(BlobEndPoint, new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(AccountName,
                AccountSecurityKey));
```

Comment: Where do you want me to use URI? It works for me like [my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549634/java-azure-request-signing/12549855#12549855)