# Azure blob storage error showing "Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using restapi to fetch data from azure blob storage using the access keys.
I have a postman collection which i can use to generate the signature string for the azure using the access keys.

But when i implement the same logic in java language it fails.
It is giving me the error **"403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.: [`AuthenticationFailed`Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly inclu... (435 bytes)]"**

here is the postman test pre req part which generate the signature string.

```
    // Should be UTC GMT string
    pm.environment.set("utcStr", new Date().toUTCString());

    // Get hash of all header-name:value
    const headers = pm.request.getHeaders({ ignoreCase: true, enabled: true });

    // Construct Signature value for Authorization header
    var signatureParts = [
      pm.request.method.toUpperCase(),
      headers["content-encoding"] || "",
      headers["content-language"] || "",
      headers["content-length"]  || "",
      //    pm.request.body ? pm.request.body.toString().length || "" : "",
      headers["content-md5"] || "",
      headers["content-type"] || "",
      headers["x-ms-date"] ? "" : (pm.environment.get("utcStr") || ""),
      headers["if-modified-since"] || "",
      headers["if-match"] || "",
      headers["if-none-match"] || "",
      headers["if-unmodified-since"] || "",
      headers["range"] || ""
    ];

    // Construct CanonicalizedHeaders
    const canonicalHeaderNames = [];
    Object.keys(headers).forEach(key => {
      if (key.startsWith("x-ms-")) {
          canonicalHeaderNames.push(key);
      }
    });
    // Sort headers lexographically by name
    canonicalHeaderNames.sort();

    const canonicalHeaderParts = [];
    canonicalHeaderNames.forEach(key => {
      let value = pm.request.getHeaders({ ignoreCase: true, enabled: true })[key];

      // Populate variables
      value = pm.environment.replaceIn(value);

      // Replace whitespace in value but not if its within quotes
      if (!value.startsWith("\"")) {
        value = value.replace(/\s+/, " ");
      }

      canonicalHeaderParts.push(`${key}:${value}`);
    });

    // Add headers to signature
    signatureParts.push.apply(signatureParts, canonicalHeaderParts);

    // Construct CanonicalizedResource
    const canonicalResourceParts = [
      `/${pm.environment.get("storeAcc")}${pm.request.url.getPath()}`
    ];
    const canonicalQueryNames = [];
    pm.request.url.query.each(query => {
      canonicalQueryNames.push(query.key.toLowerCase());
    });
    canonicalQueryNames.sort();
    canonicalQueryNames.forEach(queryName => {
      const value = pm.request.url.query.get(queryName);

      // NOTE: This does not properly explode multiple same query params' values
      // and turn them into comma-separated list
      canonicalResourceParts.push(`${queryName}:${value}`);
    });
    // Add resource to signature
    signatureParts.push.apply(signatureParts, canonicalResourceParts);

    console.log("Signature Parts", signatureParts);
 
    // Now, construct signature raw string
    const signatureRaw = signatureParts.join("\n");

    console.log("Signature String", JSON.stringify(signatureRaw));

    // Hash it using HMAC-SHA256 and then encode using base64
    const storageKey = pm.variables.get("accountKey");
    const signatureBytes = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(signatureRaw,    CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(storageKey));
    console.log("signatureBytes",signatureBytes);
    const signatureEncoded = signatureBytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

    console.log("signatureEncoded",signatureEncoded);
    console.log("Storage Account", pm.environment.get("storeAcc"));
    console.log("Storage Key", storageKey);

    // Finally, make it available for headers
    pm.environment.set("sigStr",
       `SharedKey ${pm.environment.get("storeAcc")}:${signatureEncoded}`);
```

This code works and the signature i generate is authenticated  and i get access to blob apis.

but i implemented the same code in java and every time it gives me the same problem "403 Authentication error."

**Java code**

```
    public String generateOauthHeader(String method, UserDetails userFields, String baseUrl, String azureFileListUrl)  {

        String key = userFields.getAccountKey();

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        String startDate = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        
        String stringToSign = method + "\\n\\n\\n\\n\\napplication/json\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\nx-ms-date:" + "Tue, 05 Jul 2022 11:45:00 "
                + "GMT\\nx-ms-version:2020-04-08\\n/" + userFields.getAccountName() + "/"
                + userFields.getContainerName();

        if (null != azureFileListUrl) {
            azureFileListUrl =azureFileListUrl.replace("?", "");
            azureFileListUrl =azureFileListUrl.replace("=", ":");
            String[] paramlist = azureFileListUrl.split("&");

            stringToSign = stringToSign + "\\n" + paramlist[1] + "\\n" + paramlist[0];
        }
        stringToSign="\""+stringToSign+"\"";
        System.err.println("Signature string  =  " + stringToSign);
        String signature = getHMAC256(key, stringToSign);

        signature = "SharedKey " + userFields.getAccountName() + ":" + signature;
        System.err.println("Final Signature string  =  " + signature);
        return signature;
    }

    private static String getHMAC256(String accountKey, String signStr) {
        String signature = null;
        try {
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(accountKey), "HmacSHA256");
            Mac sha256HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            sha256HMAC.init(secretKey);
            signature = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256HMAC.doFinal(signStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return signature;
    }
```

I am adding below two string which are generated around same time.

The sample signatureString before signing are identical. I have printed and checked them as well.

```
postman= "GET\n\n\n\n\napplication/json\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:Tue, 05 Jul 2022 11:45:00 GMT\nx-ms-version:2020-04-08\n/osmosconnectortest/blobcontainer\ncomp:list\nrestype:container"

code = "GET\n\n\n\n\napplication/json\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:Tue, 05 Jul 2022 11:44:56 GMT\nx-ms-version:2020-04-08\n/osmosconnectortest/blobcontainer\ncomp:list\nrestype:container"
```

EDIT:
here are the headers sent with the request.

```
      requestHeaders.put("x-ms-date", "Tue, 05 Jul 2022 11:45:00 GMT");
      requestHeaders.put("x-ms-version", "2020-04-08");
      requestHeaders.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
      requestHeaders.put("Authorization", "SharedKey accountName:yvfdsfdssdfF0lGGtEWGU+b7BqFY0UHMkvI=
");
```

Comment: did you try the solution given in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12549855/9988142 ?

Comment: Can you share the headers you are sending with the request?

Comment: i added the headers in the post. Please check.

Comment: Did anyone get solution for this ? I am facing this issue and have tried all the steps mentioned on this page but all in vain.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with the following line of code:

```
requestHeaders.put("x-ms-date", "Tue, 05 Jul 2022 11:45:00 GMT");
```

Essentially in your request headers, you are sending the date as `Tue, 05 Jul 2022 11:45:00 GMT` however in your `stringToSign` you are sending the date as `Tue, 05 Jul 2022 11:44:56 GMT` in `x-ms-date`. This would cause the `stringToSign` that you are sending and the one computed by the server to mismatch and thus resulting in different authorization header values.

To fix this, please ensure that the value for `x-ms-date` header is the same in both `stringToSign` and your request headers. I would recommend passing the date object to `generateOauthHeader` method and use the same date object in your request headers for `x-ms-date`.

Comment: that is not the issue.  i have also checked that.  i used same time in both header and stringToSign.  but it did not work.

Comment: I just went with the data you shared. Can you edit your question and include the value of `stringToSign` and also the detailed error message. The error message should contain the `stringToSign` computed by the server.

Comment: i also tried the code given in the link by stackoverflow.com/a/12549855/9988142.   still got the same error.
i will print the error message and post it here in few minutes.